# Div appears to have no content as nested divs are floated

Tags: html, overflow

I have a container with several floated divs within it. I want the div to stretch to the full height of it's content.

I have tried adding `overflow:visible` to the container to make it expand and also added a `clear` but neither seem to work.

Live site link available [here](http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/snood.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put something not floated in the div and clear that.

```
<div class="magical-div>
   <div class="float1"> content </div>
   <div class="float2"> content </div>
   <div style="display:block;clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```